# Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow

Tags: android, android-cursor

I try to find some phone contact and show it in my app, but I get an error:

```
Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 370 rows, 38 columns.
```

This is my code:

```
Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);  
        String aNumberFromContacts[] = new String[contacts.getCount()];  
        int i = 0;

        int numberFieldColumnIndex = contacts.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.NUMBER);

        while(contacts.moveToNext()) {

            String number = contacts.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);
            aNumberFromContacts[i] =    number ;
        i++;
        }

        contacts.close();
```

Can you guess what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The negative number implies that the column you were looking for is non-existant. Try using 1, if that doesn't crash, then you can be assured that the issue is in getting the column index. 
Try this instead:

```
contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
```